How to type Vietnamese with tones on a Chromebook?
On Android, using Gboard, all I have to do is long press e.g., "a", and I get tons of choices for which kind of Vietnamese "a" I wish to enter.
But on a Chromebook, yes with "VI" showing in the toolbar meaning that I have successfully turned on Google's Vietnamese input, I can't figure out how to see the choices of which kind of "a" I want, so I am stuck with plain "a".
And there is no tag for input-methods here I can add.
